# How to define that component passed must have certain props but allow extra props too

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am passing a component as a prop.

This is defined as below.

```
export type TableProps<T> = {
  contents: T[],
  loadContents: () => Promise<T[]>
};
```

This works fine, but I'd like to update this definition to say, at least above props should exist, but to allow additional props.

Is there a definition I can use to do this. For instance, I'd like a component with the following signature to be accepted.

```
type Props = {
  onChangeMark: (val: string) => void,
  ...TableProps<Attendance>
};
```

I've tried defining them as an interface but they are still being rejected.

```
interface TableProps<T> {
  contents: T[],
  loadContents: () => Promise<T[]>
};
```

**Update**

I think this demostrates the issues I am having [Link](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVZOoJYDsAuApgE5QCGAxoWALICeAkgSeVWAN5gAeAXGLgFcAtgCMSYAL4BudPjoAHagGE4Q+XFyECYALxgAFPOJx5fekyKlKhAJS6AfGDK46M9KjmKwABWPyAzrq0jMxWbABkHGB0fIKi4tLoUAK4FPjYGmAAolxkajCEDPmEQlr4ZOka+pxcQQCMADTRQQBMEny+Jv527KgS7gBuZMRgFKrqmgR8KmoaZUE5efIFRcslZRUZuDJAA)

**Update 2**

@Rajesh 's  solution doesnt seem to work , have tried [here](https://flow.org/try/#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)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
interface IDummy {
  value: string;
  propName: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

What this will do is, it will force you to pass `value` and `propName` properties in object but you can have any other properties.

[Sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IDummy%20%7B%0D%0A%09value%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20propName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(obj%3A%20IDummy)%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(obj)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atest(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20'value'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20propName%3A%20'key'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20'foo'%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Atest(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20'foo'%0D%0A%7D))

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in cases like this is to define `Props` as a union of `TableProps` and per-component props:

```
type Props = TableProps<Attendance> & {
  onChangeMark: (val: string) => void
};
```

In that case I would keep `TableProps` as an object type, not an interface.

It is also possible to use interfaces if both `TableProps` and `Props` are defined as interfaces like this:

```
interface TableProps<T> {
  contents: T[],
  loadContents(): Promise<T[]>
}

interface Props extends TableProps<Attendance> {
  onChangeMark(val: string): void
}
```

I think that Flow might have an easier time with the interface solution. But I don't have any particular evidence to back up that hunch.

Comment: I did try doing the union and it didnt work , i believe the union does the same as spreading. Ive created the following which I think demonstrates the issue https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVZOoJYDsAuApgE5QCGAxoWALICeAkgSeVWAN5gAeAXGLgFcAtgCMSYAL4BudPjoAHagGE4Q+XFyECYALxgAFPOJx5fekyKlKhAJS6AfGDK46M9KjmKwABWPyAzrq0jMxWbABkHGB0fIKi4tLoUAK4FPjYGmAAolxkajCEDPmEQlr4ZOka+pxcQQCMADTRQQBMEny+Jv527KgS7gBuZMRgFKrqmgR8KmoaZUE5efIFRcslZRUZuDJAA

Answer (score 1):

The problem runs deeper than it appears. It's slightly contrived, but can be highlighted by anonymising the type names, as done [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBiccYAvGAN5gAeAXGAHYCuAtgEZ4BOYAvgNyZcBAEIBDHhWKkAZFTBYGLDtz6Ds+IiUKNyYABQ4ucHA2kBKcgD4wYxlkGoozRgGMMASzi6o+gCZiGGIM4lyWlLzoAG4SYADmZtq6FFCCQA).

```
/* @flow */

type Foo = { x: number };
type Bar = Foo & { y: number };
type FooFn = (prop: Foo) => any;

function f(data: Bar) {}

var g: FooFn = f;
```

The above code produces the following error.

```
10:     var g: FooFn = f;
                       ^ function. This type is incompatible with
10:     var g: FooFn = f;
               ^ FooFn
The first parameter is incompatible:
4:     type FooFn = (prop: Foo) => any;
                           ^ Foo. This type is incompatible with
5:     type Bar = Foo & { y: number };
                        ^ object type
Property `y` is incompatible:
5:     type Bar = Foo & { y: number };
                        ^ property `y`. Property not found in
4:     type FooFn = (prop: Foo) => any;
                           ^ Foo
```

---

#### What does it say?

- We are trying to assign a variable `g` of type `FooFn` a value `f`.
- The function declaration for `f` gives it the type `(Bar) => any`.
- `FooFn` is really just `(Foo) => any`.

This is what is creating the problem: the LHS type is not the same as RHS type. We can say that `g` extends `f`, in the way that `g` takes an argument the extends `f`. This type of relationship is called **contra-variance**. You can read more about it [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/). I would also recommend watching a portion of [a talk](https://youtu.be/JZPXzJ5tp9w?t=8m12s) from 8:12 to 9:10.

Truth be told, Flow cannot captupe contra-variant relationships (see [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/#toc-more-specific-inputs-bad) and [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAdgFwKYBOUAhgMZ5gBiccYA3qmGAB4BcYWArgLYBGhqAL7ps+ImQoAhYgTB5m+LABMAzlRr1GYAJ7sufAcNRK8pGDIoA3GWCg121OAG5jp8wSs3eM9tIIvUYGBvWQBeWxoXO1pwkIDXMwswa1koLEd2AAoASjBQgD51ZwT3T1SsPyzcgrA-AKC0vzzbdMjUNMdmxpl4k0SPZJtoyiwsx2rC4ixtFz7SwdkQkay-CbApmfQGmhHmpawXfa6dg9QgA)).

---

#### What can you do?

Nothing much, really. All the options that you have are unpleasant to say the least.

1. Suppress flow with `// $FlowFixMe` comments (see [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex)).
2. Define your functions `f` and `g` such that they are not contra-variant (can be difficult, may even be impossible).
3. Declare your types independently, i.e., **D**o **R**epeat **Y**ourself.
4. Try a *hack* that ultimately undermines the use of a static type checker as [answered by Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48583758/1343488) and as done [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBiccYAvGAN6phgAeAXGAHYCuAtgEZ4BOANDTABtAM4YeAS2YBzALpM2XXgIC+Abky4CAIQCGPckRJgAZFTBYFHbgfWpgwMAD0wAFQAWBEbvYFdIpmx8MD0DCmI4TWCIwmZDAAocHjgcJgiASnIAPjBdZiwNVChWZgBjDAk4OKh4gBNdDF0mUMzKFXQAN30waTSSWMMoDSA).

Your call.

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help.

```
type MyInterface ={| x: number |};

type Props = {| ...MyInterface, ...{| y: number |} |}
```